# Too Many Samples = Unrealistic?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've tried experimenting with the amount of samples, the size of the tiles, etc.

Do you think TOO much samples may make it too, like, just too clean?

What do you think would be a good preset so you JUST remove the noise, and it (the image) isn't TOTALLY clean.

I have to post links due to file size:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdoah.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP9AB.jpg

You see how it's like almost too many samples? I only messed with the blurs and glow effects on PDN, but you know what I mean?

Maybe its just because I'm visually justified to darker scenes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "clean".. But no, I don't think there is such a thing as "too many samples".

Comment: If you have a proper shader, too many samples _cannot_ be a problem.

Comment: I'm gonna post two examples. FIRST one is like, 500 samples or so. The SECOND one is more like 1000.

Comment: I agree with Gandalf3: I don't mind too clean, but I would add that to keep render times within the  my lifetime, I always set the samples according to the amount of noise I can tolerate. Depending on the resolution of the final image there is also a point where increasing the number of samples doesn't yield any visible changes. In the case of fireflies increasing the samples might make things worse. It's hard to come up with a single setting that works for all situations. Noise can come out of many different factors. At the end is whatever works for you...

Comment: What's realistic about a blocky character anyway?

Comment: I think if your image feels too "clean" you might need to add more variation with textures and such.

Comment: :/ It's just a quick little render. I'm not a huge commercial artist/graphics designer. It's just for my friends.

Comment: @BinaryGreen I don't think cegaton meant that in a bad way, but IMO there is nothing wrong with having a realistic blocky character either.

Comment: @BinaryGreen That doesn't mean you can't add some scratches, smudges and whatever. The amount of samples can't improve any image in the way you want.

Answer (score 5):

No. Larger sample numbers make the image more *accurate*. If images appear to lack variation and imperfections, (I assume that's what you mean by clean) you can manually add them. This may include

- Particle systems in the air for dust
- Manually added light 'shafts'
- scratches on surfaces
- fading, or slightly different shades of colors
- high amounts of randomness (not weirdness, RANDOMNESS)

All of these can go to make sure your picture look less 'perfect' although most of the time, you don't need to add them.
It all depends on how closely the final will be observed, and how critical your audience is. (or how *dirty*, being the opposite of *clean*, you feel comfortable with.

Comment: I would say you do _need_ to add them; otherwise, good answer.

Comment: The first paragraph is misleading.. More samples do **not** increase resolution, nor sharpness.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I agree, although I would say that if anti-aliasing was enabled there would be higher-sharpie less-pixely edges.

Comment: Well I guess "sharpness" is kind of subjective.. You could just as easily say that anti-aliasing smooths out sharp pixelated edges :P

Comment: How about pointier. pixelated edges look pointy to me.